# UITextField shadow does not display when editing

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, core-graphics

I want to draw the text in an UITextField with a shadow. In order to do this, I have subclassed UITextField, and implemented the `drawTextInRect:` method as follows:

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Create shadow color
    float colorValues[] = {0.21875, 0.21875, 0.21875, 1.0};
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGColorRef shadowColor = CGColorCreate(colorSpace, colorValues);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Create shadow
    CGSize shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2, 2);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, shadowOffset, 0, shadowColor);
    CGColorRelease(shadowColor);

    // Render text
    [super drawTextInRect:rect];    
}
```

This works great for when the text field is not editing, but as soon as editing begins, the shadow disappears. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: I've seen this before on Mac OS X, and in that case it was because the field editor didn't grab the shadow attributes from the `NSTextField` and hence didn't show the shadow. Don't know if there's field editors in iOS, but I thought I'd comment.

Comment: I did some googling and it doesn't look like UITextFields use field editors, so ignore my previous comment.

Comment: you do realize that adding a drop shadow to text this small on iOS will render the text nearly unreadable.

Comment: Where did I specify the text size?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for following component

[image]

```
@interface AZTextField ()
- (void)privateInitialization;
@end

@implementation AZTextField

static CGFloat const kAZTextFieldCornerRadius = 3.0;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (!self) return nil;
    [self privateInitialization];
    return self;
}

// In case you decided to use it in a nib
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (!self) return nil;
    [self privateInitialization];
    return self;
}

- (void)privateInitialization
{
    self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;

    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 5.0f);
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;

    self.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 4;

    // This code is better to be called whenever size of the textfield changed,
    // so if you plan to do that you can add an observer for bounds property
    UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:kAZTextFieldCornerRadius];
    self.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
}

@end
```

Couple of things to consider:

- You want to set borderStyle to none, otherwise you'll end up with
  UIKit putting subviews into your textfield
- Depending on the Xcode
  version you might want to link QuartzCore and to `#import
  <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`
- For more complex appearance you can still
  use shadow properties of the layer and move the drawing code itself
  into the `drawRect:` method, but jake_hetfield was right if you
  override drawRect you don't want to call super, especially in the end
  of the method
- As for the text drawing (you can see that it sticks to
  close to the component borders), you have a separate
  `drawTextInRect:` and `drawPlaceholderInRect:` method that draws the
  text and placeholder respectively
- You can use UIColor method for
  colors and call CGColor property, it makes code more readable and
  easier to maintain

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @jake_hetfield answer I created a custom `UITextField` that uses an internal label to do the drawing, check it out:

`ShadowTextField` .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ShadowTextField : UITextField

// properties to change the shadow color & offset
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *textShadowColor;
@property (nonatomic) CGSize textShadowOffset;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
               font:(UIFont *)font 
          textColor:(UIColor *)textColor 
        shadowColor:(UIColor *)shadowColor 
       shadowOffset:(CGSize)shadowOffset;

@end
```

`ShadowTextField` .m file

```
#import "ShadowTextField.h"

@interface ShadowTextField ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *internalLabel;
@end

@implementation ShadowTextField
@synthesize internalLabel = _internalLabel;
@synthesize textShadowColor = _textShadowColor;
@synthesize textShadowOffset = _textShadowOffset;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
               font:(UIFont *)font 
          textColor:(UIColor *)textColor 
        shadowColor:(UIColor *)shadowColor 
       shadowOffset:(CGSize)shadowOffset
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        // register to my own text changes notification, so I can update the internal label
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(handleUITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification) 
                                                     name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                                   object:nil];

        self.font = font;
        self.textColor = textColor;

        self.textShadowColor = shadowColor;
        self.textShadowOffset = shadowOffset;
    }
    return self;
}

// when the user enter text we update the internal label 
- (void)handleUITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
{
    self.internalLabel.text = self.text;

    [self.internalLabel sizeToFit];
}

// init the internal label when first needed
- (UILabel *)internalLabel
{
    if (!_internalLabel) {
        _internalLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        [self addSubview:_internalLabel];

        _internalLabel.font = self.font;
        _internalLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return _internalLabel;
}

// override this method to update the internal label color
// and to set the original label to clear so we wont get two labels
- (void)setTextColor:(UIColor *)textColor
{
    [super setTextColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    self.internalLabel.textColor = textColor;
}

// override this method to update the internal label text
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text
{
    [super setText:text];

    self.internalLabel.text = self.text;

    [self.internalLabel sizeToFit];
}

- (void)setTextShadowColor:(UIColor *)textShadowColor
{
    self.internalLabel.shadowColor = textShadowColor;
}

- (void)setTextShadowOffset:(CGSize)textShadowOffset
{
    self.internalLabel.shadowOffset = textShadowOffset;
}

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // don't draw anything
    // we have the internal label for that...
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_internalLabel release];
    [_textShadowColor release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Here is how you use it in your view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ShadowTextField *textField = [[ShadowTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30) 
                                                                   font:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0] 
                                                              textColor:[UIColor whiteColor] 
                                                            shadowColor:[UIColor redColor] 
                                                           shadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1) ] ;
    textField.text = @"This is some text";    
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do the drawing of the label yourself. Remove

```
[super drawTextInRect:rect]
```

And instead draw your own label. I haven't tried this but it could look something like this:

```
// Declare a label as a member in your class in the .h file and a property for it:
UILabel *textFieldLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *textFieldLabel;

// Draw the label
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (self.textFieldLabel == nil) {
        self.textFieldLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect] autorelease];
        [self.view addSubview:myLabel];
    }

    self.textFieldLabel.frame = rect;
    self.textFieldLabel.text = self.text;

    /** Set the style you wish for your label here **/
    self.textFieldLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.textFieldLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2,2);
    self.textFieldLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    // Do not call [super drawTextInRect:myLabel] method if drawing your own text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop calling super and render the text yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried with the standard shadow properties of the CALayer? it usually is enough and it is lot simpler. Try something like this with a regular UITextField:

```
self.inputContainer.layer.shadowColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.inputContainer.layer.shadowRadius=8.0f;
self.inputContainer.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
self.inputContainer.layer.shadowOffset=CGSizeMake(0, 4);
```

You need to import QuartzCore first of course!

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: A shadow for the *text*, not the entire view.